# concatenation of text

Tags: android, text, concatenation, android-edittext

i am a new programmer in android application.

how can i concatenate the value in Edit Text?
i.e when i was entering the values in edit text box like 1234567890 the values should appear like 123-456-7890 in the same edit text.that means concatenate the by default value as "-" at every 3 digits.

is there any chance to do this

please help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this answered [question about Masked Input Using EditText Widget in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912375/masked-input-using-edittext-widget-in-android)