# Mask for EditText in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, mask

I want to limit input in the EditText of all symbols except figures, "?" And "*". How I am able to do it?

Comment: See this post has an accepted answer; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912375/masked-input-using-edittext-widget-in-android

Answer (score 1):

If you also have a maximum strict length of your string, you can use a mask. I'm not sure that it's the right solution, but it's the easiest one. An easy way use a mask in your Android programs in Android Studio is to use MaskedEditText library ([GitHub link](https://github.com/egslava/edittext-mask)).

I can not understand what does mean: **figures**, "?" And "*", so I suppose just "?" and "*". So the code is:

In your build.gradle:

```
compile 'ru.egslava:MaskedEditText:1.0.5'
```

And in your layout:

```
<br.com.sapereaude.maskedEditText.MaskedEditText
    android:id="@+id/phone_input"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:typeface="monospace"
    mask:allowed_chars="?*"
    mask:mask="##########"
    app:keep_hint="true"
    />
```

This code creates an EditText that can contain ONLY "?" and "*" and max length is 10. Feel free to ask your questions :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `TextWatch` via `addTextChangedListener`. `afterTextChanged` allows you to modify the text after it was modified.

(Keep in mind that there are many ways to modify a text field - entering text, auto-complete through IME, copy and paste). Handle those properly in the TextWatch.

Comment: please give me a example for this method

Answer (score 0):

By this, we can restrict the user to not type ? and *

```
<EditText
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textSize="@dimen/register_text_size"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:id="@+id/first_name"
   android:padding="14dp"
   android:digits="@#$%^&()_-+abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ12"
   android:singleLine="true"
   android:hint="@string/first_name"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check your input from `edittext.addTextChangeListener` method.

```
etAdjustmentInput.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {             
             //checking the length of input 
            if (etAdjustmentInput.getText().toString().trim().length()<=0){
                 // if length less then or equals 0 show warning or make button not clickable
                tvAdjustmentInfoOk.setClickable(false);
                tvAdjustmentInfoOk.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.time_color));
            }
            else {

                 // input length greater then 0 now check the input type according to your requirement 
                tvAdjustmentInfoOk.setClickable(true);
                tvAdjustmentInfoOk.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
                if(s.equals("?")){
                 //do your task
                  }
                else{ // whatever you want to tell the user 
                  }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Inside `onTextChanged` method you can restrict the user to `maximum length` and also you can check the `input type` according to your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Try this

From this code you can enter 0 to 9 digits and only two special character ? and *.

```
<EditText
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/first_name"
   android:digits="?*1234567890"
   android:singleLine="true"
   />
```

Comment: Can you add a short description?

Comment: From this code you can enter 0 to 9 digits and only two special character ? and *.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private EditText editText;
private String blockCharacterSet = "?*";

private InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

        if (source != null && !blockCharacterSet.contains(("" + source))) {
            return "";
        }
        return null;
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter });
}
```

}