# How to format text by whitespaces?

Tags: java, android, string-formatting, number-formatting, decimalformat

In an Android application I have a field where the user should type some 14-digits number like 12345678901234.
I want this number to look like 12 3456 7890 1234.
I've tried to do this by code:

```
if((s.length() == 2 || s.length() == 7 || s.length() == 12)){
s.insert(s.length(), " ");
}
```

But when the user starts to type in the middle of the text, my code works wrong.

I've tried to use the DecimalFormat class:

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("##,####.#### ####");
String formattedText = decimalFormat.format(Double.parseDouble(etContent.getText().toString()));
```

but I receive an IllegalArgumentException.
 Any ideas how to do that?
P.S The main problem is I should format text "right now" like:
1
12
12 3
12 34
12 345
12 3456
12 3456 7
12 3456 78
12 3456 789
12 3456 7890
12 3456 7890 1
12 3456 7890 12
12 3456 7890 123
12 3456 7890 1234

Comment: An IllegalArgumentException on which argument?

Comment: new DecimalFormat("##,####.#### ####")

Comment: that line will not give.. might be second  line can give\

Comment: You should consider doing masked input

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912375/masked-input-using-edittext-widget-in-android

Comment: decimalFormat.format(Double.parseDouble("12345678901234")) should be working. it'll give you comma separated value which you can replace with space.

Answer (score 1):

@Karthika PB I think it will remove the 3rd character i.e 12 4567 like it will come.
Try this

```
    String seq = editText.getText().toString().trim();

    String newstring = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < seq.length(); i++) {

        if (i == 2 || i == 6 || i == 10) {
            newstring = newstring + " " + seq.charAt(i);

        } else
            newstring = newstring + seq.charAt(i);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try this remove white spaces and insert space

 String seq=etContent.getText().toString().trim();//to remove white spaces


         String newstring="";
    for(int i=0;i<seq.length();i++){

        if(i==2 || i==7 || i==14){
            newstring=newstring+" ";

        }
        else
        newstring=newstring+seq.charAt(i);
    }
```

use newstring which will have the formatted text

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the substring method:

```
String formattedText = s.substring(0,2) + " " + s.substring(2,6)+
         " " + s.substring(6,10) + " " + s.substring(10,14);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these codes in TextWatcher.afterTextChanged(Editable)

```
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (changeText) {
                Log.d("afterTextChanged", "afterTextChanged");
                String txt = s.toString();
                txt = txt.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                changeText = false;
                s.clear();
                int index = 0;
                for (char c:txt.toCharArray()) {
                    if (index == 2
                            || index == 7
                            || index == 12) {

                        s.append(' ');
                        index++;
                    }
                    s.append(c);
                    index++;
                }
                changeText = true;
            }
        }
```

changeText is a boolean tag that prevent infinite loop.

Comment: And the 'changeText' init value should be 'true'.