# How to add specific character after at every 10 character on edittext

Tags: java, android

I have a edittext on which i want to add special character "!" after every 10 characters.
So for example if i write :

```
9090909090!164960375830!0583948
```

And when i remove text from then it will auto remove "!".

I have tried `addTextChangedListener` but wont able to achieved it.

How can i get it ?

Comment: Use textwatcher is correct way

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Masked Input Using EditText Widget in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912375/masked-input-using-edittext-widget-in-android)