# Edittext - Mask with date format

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout, input-mask

[image]

I use `redMadRobot/input-mask` library to mask edittext. But I need space between DD / MM  / YYYY like in example image and `/` symbol must be always visible. But I can't do it with this library as I see.

Code :

```
const val DATE_MASK = "[00]{/}[00]{/}[9900]"

MaskedTextChangedListener.Companion.installOn(
            editText, DATE_MASK, object : MaskedTextChangedListener.ValueListener {
                override fun onTextChanged(
                    maskFilled: Boolean,
                    extractedValue: String,
                    formattedValue: String
                ) {
                    //transactions
                }
            }
        )
```

Is there any native edittext property to make this desgin or can you suggest another library?

Comment: `or can you suggest another library` this will get your question closed as seeking recommendations for software libraries. you could always clone that library locally and make it do what you'd like to

Comment: @a_local_nobody yes but unfortunately I can't do this. I've been dealing with this for hours. It seems very difficult.

Comment: `yes but unfortunately I can't do this` why not ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody because I can't find any property in this library about text aligment like as example image and I don't know any other way to do this.

Comment: i think this design can not be done with only edittext @a_local_nobody

Comment: where did i say that it was possible using only an edittext @EricHollsen ? :) i said OP should clone the library they're using and make changes to it as they need to

Comment: you could try looking at something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912375/masked-input-using-edittext-widget-in-android) but i don't think there's a way of doing this by default no, you'd have to build or code something for it

Comment: yeah you didn't say but in this library, one edittext is used. So that's why I think this can not be done with this library. @a_local_nobody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Library author here.
`input-mask-android` is about text formatting, but your question looks more layout-related.

Three `EditText` components plus two `/` labels between them might do the trick. `setOnEditorActionListener` and `TextWatcher` listeners will help with cursor movement.

Or you could just put a couple of spaces within curly brackets and call it a day:  `[00]{ / }[00]{ / }[9900]`

I'd also suggest reading more about our [affine masks](https://github.com/RedMadRobot/input-mask-android/wiki/2.1-Affine-Masks), and then use a couple of patterns for the sake of year correctness:

- `[00]{ / }[00]{ / }[00]`
- `[00]{ / }[00]{ / }[0000]`